# Moving panels on button press C#

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, panels

I'm confused as to how I can accomplish this. I want to press the buttons and then the bottom panels go to the top and then open, if that makes sense.

This is essentially what I have
https://i.stack.imgur.com/adLoQ.png

And I only have the basic code for button clicks

```
private void CP_OneFbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: At least have a go yourself.

Comment: I've been trying to do it for about 4 days now and got nowhere :(

Comment: Well what have you tried in those 4 days, other than create the event handler?

Comment: I was trying to give it a status to check if the elevator was going UP or DOWN and either move or close etc. Didn't work and ended up scrapping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you need to change Panel's Location property like this:

```
panel1.Location = new Point(X,Y);
```

If you don't know exact coordinates,then you can handle Form MouseMove event (temporarily)

```
 private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = e.X + "," + e.Y;
    }
```

Move mouse to the location where you want to panel move and note coordinates, then handle button click event and change panel's location

```
private void CP_OneFbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       panel1.Location = new Point(X,Y); // type your X and Y coordinates here
       panel1.Visible = true; // Display the panel
    }
```